# Вывести все события по дате pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Имеется таблица логов в формате csv,колонки date,user,event_type,parameter, дата указана по такому типу 2020-04-01_00:01:08,  я хочу чтобы в выводе были все события начиная с 2020-04-18_00:00:16 по
2020-04-18_23:59:50

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("log (1).csv")
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2020-04-01_00:01:08', periods=200, freq='D')
df = df.set_index(['date'])
print(df.loc['2020-04-18_00:00:16':'2020-04-18_23:59:50'])
```

при выполнении кода выдает ошибку could not convert string to Timestamp

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подчёркивание между датой и временем `Pandas` не понимает. Если заменить его на пробел, то всё работает:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame()
df['date'] = pd.date_range('2020-04-01 00:01:08', periods=200, freq='D')
df = df.set_index(['date'])
print(df.loc['2020-04-18 00:00:16':'2020-04-18 23:59:50'])
```

Вывод:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: []
Index: [2020-04-18 00:01:08]
```

Если же у вас где-то в готовом файле есть такое подчёркивание, то его легко заменить и преобразовать таки строку в датувремя:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2020-04-18_00:00:16', '2020-04-18_23:59:50']})
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'].str.replace('_', ' '))
```

Comment: Все замечательно, но осталось одно, теперь при выполнении всплывает ошибка
Length of values (200) does not match length of index (200000)
не подскажете в чем беда

Comment: @BorisBandit Это значит, что в вашем файле `"log (1).csv"` 200000 значений, а вы пытаетесь записать в колонку `date` только 200 значений, сгенерированных `pd.date_range`. Ну, если я правильно понял, в чём проблема.

Comment: и как это исправить?

Comment: А в самом файле с логом даты и времени нет? Надо оттуда брать наверняка

Comment: есть колонка date, в ней данные типа 2020-04-18 23:53:43

Comment: Ну тогда сразу просто указывайте при чтении файла параметр `parse_dates='date'` и всё, будет колонка с нормальными датами у вас.